# menu css3 hovering over links

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my first menu by hovering over links but when I hover, the ul within the first ul isn't showing.

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2FLMD/

So basically I have a nav with a **ul** and **links** within that. Then I have another **ul** within the first link called Log In. Inside that second ul are two links with one input elements inside each.

**HTML**

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">LOG IN</a></li>
            <ul>
                <li>Username: &nbsp;<input type="text" name="username">              </li>
                <li>Password: &nbsp;<input type="password" name="password"></li>

            </ul>
        <li><a href="#">SIGN UP</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">CUSTOMER SERVICE</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">SPECIALS</a></li> 
        <input type="search" name="search"> 
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
nav ul{
background:#1C1D21;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

nav ul li{
display:inline-block;
color:white;
padding:10px 20px;
border-right:1px solid white;

}

 nav ul li a{
 color:white;
 text-decoration:none; 
 }

nav ul ul {
position:absolute;
border-top:1px solid red;
} 

 /*Where the problem seems to occur */

 nav ul ul li {
display:block; /*change to display to none */
}

/*The hovering part */ 

nav ul li:hover > ul li{
display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the html structure as your sub `ul` is not containing in the `li` and is existing as a sibling to the `li` elements:

```
<li><a href="#">LOG IN</a>
    <ul>
        <li>Username: &nbsp;<input type="text" name="username"></li>
        <li>Password: &nbsp;<input type="password" name="password"></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/2FLMD/5/)

Comment: Thanks for the answers to point out my mistake! All answers were great but I chose this one because correcting the HTML syntax allows me to hover over the second ul.

Answer (score 2):

You want to put the sub list (sub nav) inside your main list (main nav)

http://jsfiddle.net/doiks14/2FLMD/4/

The selector you have `nav ul li:hover > ul li` indicates that `nav ul li` has child of `ul li`

I simply changed the mark up to reflect what you're trying to do.

```
<li>
    <a href="#">LOG IN</a>
    <ul>
        <li>Username: &nbsp;<input type="text" name="username"></li>
        <li>Password: &nbsp;<input type="password" name="password"></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Also note that this is the semantically correct way of creating a list.

Answer (score 1):

Change `>` to `+` like this:

```
nav ul li:hover + ul li{
   display:block;
}
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/2FLMD/7/)

Note that the `ul` (you want to show) is not a direct child of the `li` which you hover on, it's just an adjacent sibling of that `li`, so we should use `+` instead of `>`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors on yout HTML markup. Here is a [`quick fix`](http://jsfiddle.net/Rc2Da/)

Answer (score 0):

Your selector wasn't formed correctly, try this:

```
 nav ul:hover ul li{
  display:block;
}
```

ref: http://jsfiddle.net/2FLMD/2/